# How to convert two different time format in one format react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Below two dates am getting from api.
 I have to convert both in  26-04-2019 12:45:43 PM" in this format . Please suggest

"26-APR-19 12:45",

"26/04/2019 12:45:43"

Thanks ..

Comment: How  do you know 12:45:43 is AM or PM , are you getting that from API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library

Example:

```
import moment from 'momentjs'
...
date_one = moment("26-APR-19 12:45","DD-MMM-YY HH:mm")
date_two = moment("26/04/2019 12:45:43","DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
console.log(date_one).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:MM:SS A") //  26-04-2019 12:45:43 PM
console.log(date_two).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:MM:SS A") //  26-04-2019 12:45:43 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) e.g.

```
moment('26-APR-19 12:45').format('MMMM Do YYYY, HH:MM:SS A');
```